# d3 Animations cause slow behavior

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition

I'm using d3 to display a heatmap. Each cell on the floor is represented by a rect in the drawing.  Checkboxes on the right allow users to filter out some of the rects, which causes an opacity change transition of about 1 second.

Every once in a while (~25% of the time), toggling the display of a large set of cells causes the browser (chrome) to come to a halt.  The page freezes up, the CPU fan starts screaming, and 10-20 seconds later, the cells disappear and everything is back to normal.

Any idea what could be causing this?  There are 7679 cells on the drawing, with varying transparency and some overlapping.

[image: heatmap]

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
//Create cells  
//-------------------------------------------------------------
var cells = svg.selectAll("rect").data(drawingData, function (d) { return d.id;});
cells.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x",              function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .attr("y",              function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
    .attr("width",          function(d) { return 4; })
    .attr("height",         function(d) { return 5; })
    .attr("fill",           function(d) { return channelcolors[d.channel]; })
    .attr("fill-opacity",   function(d) { return rssiScale(d.rssi_val); });

cells.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease("linear")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Right, 7679 objects. That's way too many objects to be fading in/out all at once. It's bogged down on the javascript side (having to execute so many changes at once). And then, because the shapes have transparency, the renderer has to composite them all and it gets killed too.

Obviously the simplest, least taxing option is not to have a transition at all.

But, one complicated option worth trying – it may or may not work – is to temporarily transfer all the rects that have to be faded in/out into the a single group, and then fade the group as a whole (i.e. not the individual cells).

Other than that, you can try staggering the transitions' start times. Meaning, each cell's transition has a delay that's a multiple of i (the cell's index). That way, at any given moment, only a percentage of the cells are being transitioned. But 1000ms duration of each cell's animation is way too long. Should be more like 100ms.